# Virus scan emails on mail server or mail client?

Tags: email, antivirus

We've written a simple email client. We've some basic whitelist/blacklist functionality in there but nothing more than that. We've noticed a few emails containing malicious code and I 'assumed' the mailserver should take care of that.

So should this be a responsibility of the mail server / host or of the email client itself?

Comment: Might wanna bump up your accep rate if you hope to get quality answers.

Answer (score 3):

**Both**

If you have to use the word `assume` you better just go ahead and handle things on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Both, either or neither.

Neither is obliged to do it. So as Robert Greiner says, you should not `assume`.

The reality is that if you are selling your email client, or even giving it away, you need to consider what your customers expect.
If you expect them to use your client alongside well configured, decent mail servers and standalone antivirus software, you might not need to do it yourself.

Just make damn sure that the end user knows what they are (and aren't) getting from you, and have an appropriate licence agreement.

You almost certainly won't be able to write and maintain your own antivirus updates, unless you can afford to spend millions on R&D each year, so if you are going to take care of it yourself, look at integrating with the API of an established (not necessarily market-leader) antivirus provider. You will probably need to pay a licence fee to integrate with and distribute their software.

However, my personal expectation would be to not rely on mail server and client and have my own desktop antivirus program.